# Error inflating the class for toolbar

Tags: android, styles, android-toolbar

I am using the toolbar for my app it works fine in the lollipop version.But in the previous version the app gets crashed.I have tried changing the styles to 
Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar but it didn't works.

Styles:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
<style name="AppThemes" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>
</style>
```

XmlToolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

Logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nidhinkumar.webviewss/nidhinkumar.webviewss.ParseMainAct}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:816)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:305)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1966)
        at nidhinkumar.webviewss.ParseMainAct.onCreate(ParseMainAct.java:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5286)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
```

ParseMainAct:

```
public class ParseMainAct extends Activity{
private static String TAG = ParseMainAct.class.getSimpleName();

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private ListView listView;
private List<Message> listMessages = new ArrayList<>();
private MessageAdapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.parseact_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


    adapter = new MessageAdapter(this);


    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Intent intent = getIntent();




}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

    Message m = new Message(message, System.currentTimeMillis());
    listMessages.add(0, m);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private class MessageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MessageAdapter(Activity activity) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listMessages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listMessages.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parselist_row, null);
        }

        TextView txtMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);
        TextView txtTimestamp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);

        Message message = listMessages.get(position);
        txtMessage.setText(message.getMessage());

        CharSequence ago = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(message.getTimestamp(), System.currentTimeMillis(),
                0L, DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL);

        txtTimestamp.setText(String.valueOf(ago));

        return view;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

parse_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/my_tool_bar" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
```

Comment: How are you trying to inflate the toolbar?

Comment: In java i am using like this                                                                                                mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

Comment: which theme you are using in manifest file from that three?

Comment: I am using MyBase.Theme

Answer (score 0):

You should create your toolbar.xml inside you layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="xxxxxx">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/main_menu_activity_toolbar"
            layout="@layout/XmlToolbar" />
```

And then inflate it your activity:

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_menu_activity_toolbar);
```

**EDIT**

Use NoActionBar in your base application theme

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

Comment: Your problem is here:  at nidhinkumar.webviewss.ParseMainAct.onCreate(ParseMainAct.java:36). Could you share this code?

Comment: I have added the ParseMainAct  also pls check it.

Answer (score 0):

May be somewhere in your app `AppTheme` or 'AppThemes' has been used. you see you have give parent theme as `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`. that means your Activity having this theme has `ActionBar`.

You cannot use `ToolBar` As long as `ActionBar`is there.

just Change `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`. and you are good to go.

Hope this will help you.

**Update**

Set your `ToolBar`as Your `ActionBar`

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
```

Comment: have you check in style-v14? I think there also you have to change it

Comment: You have to set `ToolBar` as `ActionBar` I saw in your code you have not set that. look for my Updated answer.

Comment: i have added and checked but it didn't works and whether i have to extend it as appcompactactivity or actionbaractivity

Comment: I have added the parseact_main.xml

Comment: everything looks fine. I don't see any problem here. may be you should clean your project. and run again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to made two styles.xml file one for device below lollipop and other is styles.xml (v-21) for device lollipop and above version.
Sample of style.xml

```
<style name="MyAppThemes" parent="MyTheme.Base">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
 <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>
</style>
```

Sample of style.xml(v-21)

```
 <style name="MyAppThemes" parent="MyAppThemes.Base">
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>
</style>
```

Now inside your AndroidMainfest.xml  change application theme

```
 android:theme="@style/MyAppThemes">
```

I hope it will solve your problem.